# Can siddhas travel in time?

Tags: siddhi, time

The siddhas who have several mystic powers can do a lot of things that an ordinary man cannot do.

Now, I would like to know whether they can travel in time too? Did Lord Krishna in Bhagavad Gita said about this or did any Vedas or Upanishads or Tantra Shastras?

Comment: "Spiritual Engineering" called Tantra, is about Space. Its about 'Machines' that give you control on '_Prana_' (instead of Energy) in space. You can go anywhere in the universe by covering colossal distances in space **in a moment**. You can **foresee** Past and Future (Because vibrations of every thought and every action are present in space, **all the time**). With immense Yoga power, you even can (nearly) STOP the **perception of time** for yourself. **BUT, you can NOT go beyond Time, itself.** You see, its just "engineering". We are in an inescapable 'black hole' called "Present".

Comment: Time, space and all other material manifestations and dimensions, all these are illusions!! God (our real Self or Parabrahma) is ABOVE and BEYOND time. Those Siddhas who are aware of this TRUTH manipulate time and other dimensions as per His Will. once realization dawns about the Truth, then one can easily  manipulate all of Creation, because all of Creation is a dream/illusion, OUR illusion. This advaitist thought. As @Hindu has beautifully expounded, everything is 'PRESENT' or 'NOW', time itself is just illusive and unreal  Sir :)

Comment: @Sai :) Indeed God is beyond time. Beyond _Mritu-Loka_. BUT things are NOT illusion buddy. PAST and FUTURE are Hell-Real! Karma as well its Fruit are BOTH Real. ONLY the attachments with them is "unreal". And when _BRHAMA_ himself CAN'T go beyond his life span of 100-Brahmnical years, how can a _siddha_ manipulate Time. There is illusions around only because "a sleeping man thinks of his dreams as real." Illusionary is the "WILL" of a soul itself.

Comment: @Hindu Ok Buddy :) if you would like to believe Past and Future are Hell-Real, then go ahead. Its upto you what you would like to believe and I don't disagree. As in the comment the illusion part is an Advaitist answer. Different interpretations give different conclusions and all of them are valid. But essence is same. The essence here is that everything is 'Present' as you rightly said. As for 'Brahma himself can't go beyond his life span of 100-Brahmnical years': Brahma's lifespan is not His lifespan, but the life-span of His body. one who realizes this is no longer under control of TIME.

Comment: @Hindu illusionary is the 'WILL' of a soul itself? That didn't make much sense. If you mean to say that this illusion itself was the Will of the soul, then I'm not disagreeing. If you meant something else, please clarify. Thank you for taking time to explain your viewpoint, which I do respect and learn from Sir :)

Comment: Also on a side note you mentioned karma as well as its fruit are both real. only attachments with them is unreal. You can call it however you want, but going as per your reasoning, you realize that attachment to its results is 'unreal' you detach yourself from it. Then its fruits no longer control you, isn't it. i.e. You are no longer influenced by its fruits. Therefore the very karma or its fruits are meaningless to your life-actions. Advaitins call that as 'illusion' while you say 'it is REAL, but attachment to fruits is illusion', its just case of calling it different , essence same Sir!!

Comment: @Sai :) Essence are same, but the thing is that, NOBODY IS BEYOND TIME, except Shri Vishnu and Sada-Shiva. "Life-span" of Brahma is NOT bounded by His "Birth and Death" (He doesn't have body of Flesh and Blood). His "journey" is like "Avyakat --> Vyakta --> Avyakta". Lord Brahma is the PUREST SUPER SOUL. And WHAT makes Him different from _Sat-chhit-ananda PARAMATMAN_ Vishnu, is just the "WILL" (a TIME element) He has. And when this Will vanishes, his TIME GETS OVER and He again becomes _Avyakta_ in Shiva. General Souls follow the same pattern, but we use '_Moksha_', when they become _Avyakta_.

Comment: @Hindu i like ur speculation but humbly disagree. Brahma is definitely not of flesh and blood. But the Will that u speak of is not his will but The Will of Brahman (as per ur example u consider Vishnu to be supreme so it is Vishnu's Will). By Vishnu's Will Brahma comes into existence and by Vishnu's Will he goes back into Vishnu. Will originates from Brahman and not from His Creation. Nobody is beyond time. I will just add a '-' to that statement no-BODY is beyond time (whether made of flesh or not). The soul is above and beyond time. Soul is immortal - always has been in existence my friend.

Comment: I believe that Vishnu or Brahman is no different from our jiva or soul (although I accept other beliefs too as completely valid). The difference is apparent and not real. Thus every individual is Vishnu Himself. Thus to me a siddha who has realized this Truth is also above and beyond time. Now if you believe that Vishnu is supreme and we are separate from Him. Even then Vishnu is Above and beyond time! Thus a siddha who has surrendered to Him can go above and beyond time IF Vishnu wills that to happen. Vishnu has the power to take him to as much exalted state as needed. CRUX same

Comment: @Hindu this is indeed getting too lengthy. We are both saying same thing my friend. You say that siddhas cannot control time only Vishnu can. I am saying that siddhas who have realized themselves as Brahman (or Vishnu) can control time! Basically saying same thing. Difference is that you say soul is always different from Vishnu, whereas I believe otherwise. Point is same. If you really like we can take it to chat. I am always available. just ping me once you start a room

Comment: @Sai So, what is the answer? Can they travel or not? :)

Comment: @JavaTechnical Advaitically Yes, they can, but they dont need to. Because there are only two reasons to travel through time. 1. Because you are not happy the way you are! 2. Because you are curious what happened in the past or what happened in the future. Siddhas are quite content (in fact infinitely happy with) the PRESENT, so they care not. Also the ones who are realized also have no need to know the past or the future because they know it is all illusion and the only thing that's important is the PRESENT! The only reason why they would travel back in time is if that were Divine Will :)!

Comment: Didn't Krishna himself travel in time to retrieve Sandeepani's children, Devaki's children and the dead children of one of his brahmin subjects?  There are many saints even of recent times who have appeared in multiple locations at the same time. Siddhas can conquer time and space.